# Why does java prefer the parent class in this example?

Tags: java

So in class, we are going over-loading and over-ridding though for some reason my professor could not explain why when we have two classes (a and b; as well as b extends to a) when calling a method it prefers the method in the parent class even though the parameters meet those of the child class. Yet java uses the parent one.

```
class B extends A {
  public int m(int x) {
    return 20;
  }
}

class A {
  public int m(double x) {
    return 10;
  }
}

public class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A x = new B();
    System.out.println(x.m(5));
  }
}
```

Output: 10

Comment: they are not the same methods. they have different argument types

Comment: @SharonBenAsher correct but say you switch the arguments ( int and double) in the classes it then chooses the child method

Comment: Try adding `@Override` to `a`.

Comment: because you are calling the method with an int arg. try calling with `5D` and see what happens

Comment: Are you sure the output is 10 ?

Comment: @JoopEggen, that doesn't matter. the annotation for the compiler only!

Comment: @SharonBenAsher yea it goes to 10, but why is when i put 5, and int, it goes to the double

Comment: @T.Lucas 100% ive ran it 10 times and saved it etc

Comment: @Override should result in a warning in the IDE because nothing is overridden.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Actually, the annotation is for the programmer... Once you add it, the compiler will tell you that the method does not override an existing one, and then you, as a programmer, will realize that they are not the same method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I meant that the annotation is processed at compile time and erased at run time. you should know that that is what I meant.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher i try to add the Override and nothing but the same occurs

Comment: The tldr of the linked dupe: since the two `m` methods are unrelated, the compiler only knows about `a`'s methods at compile time -- that is, it only knows about `m(double)`. So it resolves the method to that call, and fact that at runtime there's a method that _would_ have been a better fit isn't considered, since that better-fitting method is not an overload of `m(double)` (since ints aren't subtypes of doubles).

Comment: @joshau The declared type is `a`. When interfacing with the referenced object, there is no `int m(int x)`, as it's not defined in `a`.